# How to change output format for Niftynet?

Tags: output-formatting, niftynet

Is it possible to set output format in configuration file for `Niftynet`?
e.g. I would like to have my output as `png`.

My output is currently in `.nii.gz` format.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the output array in Python with [NiBabel](http://nipy.org/nibabel/):

```
import nibabel
data_array = nibabel.load('output_file.nii.gz').get_data()
# shape of data_array is [width, height, depth, time, num_channels]
```

and save the array as any other image formats.